# Rx.Observable.Of error is not catched

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs5, rxjs-dom

i want to return token from localStorage and catch error.

```
Observable.of(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')).token)
.catch((er) => Observable.of(console.log(er))
```

But it does not catch it. Interesting is when I use try catch method ,I can catch error

```
  try {
      return Observable.of(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')).token);
    } catch (er) {
      console.log(er);
    }
```

What is the reason of that? Hope someone give advice.[image]
Thanks

Comment: can you put getItem code in your post?

Comment: @mickaelw .Ok I attached.Please check

Comment: What's your error? For me, I just have undefined variable, but zero error which are catched

Comment: error was cannot read token of undefined.

Comment: Do you have stringify currentUser value when you set the localstorage?

Comment: Thanks @mickaelw. Problem is solved already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the error is thrown before it's result is passed into `Observable.of`. This is unrelated to RxJS, that's how the order of statements is executed by the JS interpreter.

You can do for example:

```
Observable.defer(() => Observable.of(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')).token))
  .catch(???) // returning Observable.of(console.log(er) is probably useless
```

Comment: Thanks @martin. it worked like a charm. But can you provide another way of getting token from localstorage and catch error. That's because, overall solution to get token by this way is not ideal. Thanks in advance.